# Parent POM Missing on deployed Github package

Tags: maven, github, github-actions

Using Actions from Github packages, a jar was successfully deployed. The jar and the pom is viewable.

A second project makes use of that jar as a dependency, however maven attempts to download the parent pom and not the jar; resulting in a

> Could not resolve dependencies error

How can I tell maven to only download the jar?

pom does have a parent:

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>app-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.test.app</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
<artifactId>app-test</artifactId>
```

other app uses the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.test.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>app-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

The settings.xml has all the correct information to point to the github package setup for the repository.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use a jar as dependency, Maven needs to also resolve the POM and the parent POM (and much more) to determine the transitive dependencies.

For example: The parent POM of `app-test` defines a dependency. Then this is also a dependency of `app-test` and needs to be resolved for the transitive dependency resolution.

Summarised: You need the parent POM as well.

My question would be: How could the be built in the first place if the parent POM is missing?

Comment: This problem comes from migrating a project from a manual deployment to using CI.
The jar dependency in question was built locally on a deploy box after checking out the project in it's entirety .
Now with CI, the idea was was to build the components and have them available when other builds (that require them) are triggered.

Comment: The rule of thumb is: If you need something to build the jar, you also need it to use it as dependency. A dependency without its dependencies, its BOMs or its parent POM cannot be properly consumed by Maven.

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind (it probably won't) help you is the flatten maven plugin. It allows you "flatten" a POM during the build, which means that the content of the parent POM is incorporated and the reference to the parent POM is eliminated.